# How to return two values of same datatype from a single function in java?

Tags: java, return-value

I want to return two values from method which is used to get input from the user and after getting input I haev to return those values in another method as a parameter/argument.
i tried to use "return a,b" but its not working.
please suggest me the solution....
`
public static int fnInput(){

```
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter 1st Number:");
    int a = sc1.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter 2nd Number:");
    int b =  sc1.nextInt();
    
    return a,b;
```

}
`

I tried to use this array method too but this method is also not working and returning the values
`
public static int fnInput(){

```
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter 1st Number:");
    int a = sc1.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter 2nd Number:");
    int b =  sc1.nextInt();
    
    return new int[] {a ,b };
```

}
`

Comment: Change `public static int` to `public static int[]`, so the return type is an array.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of your function should be an array of `int` in that case

```
public static int[] fnInput(){

    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter 1st Number:");
    int a = sc1.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter 2nd Number:");
    int b =  sc1.nextInt();
    
    int[] result = {a ,b};
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `int[]` as the return type of you function :

```java
public static int[] fnInput(){ Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter 1st Number:");
    int a = sc1.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter 2nd Number:");
    int b =  sc1.nextInt();
    sc1.close(); // You should close Scanner objects when you're done with them
    return new int[] {a ,b };

}
```

Comment: Its a good practice to close scanner objects. However, here the scanner would be out of scope and will be deleted automatically from the memory when the function ends (in the very next line)!